# Run my script right before the execution of the main one

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a new project in Python:
it's a sort of file-locker that protects with a password whichever file I decide to lock; then, when the right password is put into my script, the file gets opened.

Now I'm stuck into this problem: how can I make my script get executed when I try to open a normal file that's been locked before without changing it (like putting a piece of code at the start of the original file or what else)?

Should I try to make a "listener" that opens at every Windows startup checking whether the registered files are being opened, so that it will block their execution (if possible, I didn't find anything like that) until another script does not finish?

Comment: FYI, this is [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), and using it alone is a terrible way to protect data. Use encryption instead.

Comment: and how much time it will be needed to decrypt bigger files? because, if I'm not wrong, when a file is encrypted and protected by a password, when the right one is given the file gets decrypted and then opened.